# Evitar que o navegador preencha o campo email e senha

Tags: html5

Quando adiciona no type de uma input o valor password e email o navegador muda o background deste input para a cor amarela e preenche os dados do usuário automaticamente. Existe uma forma de prevenir este evento:

Comment: Isso acontece com todos os navegadores ou vc está sendo específico a um apenas?

Comment: Não, a pergunta foi genérica mesmo

Comment: Gostaria de saber se tem como prevenir em todos, se não, só no google

Comment: Francis vc testou ai, consegui trocar a cor?

Comment: Troquei, mas não foi bem o que eu pensava que ia acontecer, ficou um pouco estranho ainda, mas não investi muito tempo no código. Acho que se eu alterar algumas coisas vai melhorar.

Comment: Eu tentei testar local aqui, mas não to conseguindo no meu chrome. De qq forma qq problema me fala que tento te dar uma força

Comment: Então, ele muda a cor, mas eu estou tentando um  cor rgba no fundo, mas ele não aceita

Comment: Para evitar o autocomplete, coloque assim nos campos: `autocomplete="new-email"` e `autocomplete="new-password"`

Comment: Sobre a cor testei assim no site do Santader! e funcionou! ` -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 1000px rgba(255,0,0,1) inset;`

Comment: O problema é que se você colocar um rgba mais neutro, partindo da cor branca, por exemplo, parece que a transparência fica sobre uma cor e não sobre o fundo do meu site.

Comment: Francis acredito que isso seja porque a cor amarela ainda está lá. o que esse estilo faz e colocar uma sombre interna no input, assim fazendo uma sombre interna que fica por cima da cor padrão. Repare que é um box-shadow `-webkit-box-shadow` Vc pode tentar colocar transparência no input como um todo e não no na cor com rgba para ver como fica...

Comment: É, depois vou investir mais nessa solução... Muito obrigado Hugo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Essa cor amarela até onde sei a padrão do Chrome e vc consegue removê-la assim:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 1000px #fff inset; /* muda o background color */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #333; /* muda a cor do texto*/
}
input {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
}
```

Sobre o autocomplete vc pode tirar do form inteiro

```
<form autocomplete="off">
...
</form>
```

Ou direto no input

```
<input type="email" autocomplete="off">
```

Sobre o `<input type="password">` nele o `autocomplete="off"` não vai funcionar para o Password por uma questão do engine do próprio browser. Exestem outras repostas a respeito disso. Uma forma de resolver é tendo 2 campos de password. O primeiro vc coloca `display:none`. O Browser em alguns casso só preenche o primeiro campo de password, então o segundo que estará visivel e vai ficar vazio...

**OBS:** Vc também pode fazer uma validação em duas etapas como o Google. Primeiro vc pede o e-mail e faz a validação, depois na próxima etapa vc pede o password. Assim o campo password não fica visível logo de cara pro usuário, e só aparece depois de validar o e-mail.