# Remover fundo amarelo de formulário depois de autocompletar

Tags: google-chrome

Boa noite, conforme a imagem abaixo, alguém sabe como não deixar amarelo o fundo depois de um autofill do chrome??? Já ví umas maneiras de trocar a cor, mas manter o fundo original não achei, mesmo que eu troque a cor para um branco ainda fica feio pq o formulario original é transparente. 
Obs: estou usando o materialize

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível resposta em [Evitar que o navegador preencha o campo email e senha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/299611/88361)

Comment: Não. Assim como eu disse na pergunta, ele deixa o fundo branco, não evita o fundo amarelo.

Comment: Já tentou trocar para transparente em vez de branco ou então pela cor de fundo da aplicação?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Alterar o background do input preenchido pelo autocomplete do Chrome](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256541/alterar-o-background-do-input-preenchido-pelo-autocomplete-do-chrome)

Comment: Já tentei, daí ele fica amarelo.

Comment: @oiniciante cara vc tem que usar a classe `input:-webkit-autofill` e nela colocar o estilho `-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 300px SUACOR inset;` e pronto. Vc não precisa ter o fundo transparente nesse casa. O seu fundo do inputo pode ter a mesma cor amarela do formulário. **Então sua classe ficaria assim:** `input:-webkit-autofill { -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px SUACOR inset;}` Se resolver me fala que crio uma resposta mais completa para vc entender melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o css:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

Ou

```
background-color: inherit;
```

Você também pode tentar colocar `!important` depois do valor, para forçar esse propriedade se outra estiver sendo executada após a atribuição.

```
background-color: inherit !important;
```